# Как выполнить команду если пакет установлен?

Tags: nginx, puppet

Как написать манифест для *puppet*, чтобы он проверял, установлен ли пакет *nginx*, и если установлен, то создавал файл?

Пробовал примерно так:

```
if ! defined(Package['nginx-full']) {
        file { "/opt/puppet/test_nginx4.tmp":
                ensure => "present",
                owner  => "root",
                group => "root",
                mode => '664',
    }
}
```

Comment: Ответ не знаю, но тему одобряю ))

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную задачу следующим способом:

> class base::nginx {
>
> ```
>     file { "vim_nginx":
>             ensure => 'present',
>             path => '/tmp/puppet/vim_nginx.sh',
>             source => 'puppet:///modules/base/vim_nginx.sh',
>             mode => '774',
>     }
>     exec { "highlighting":
>             command => 'bash /tmp/puppet/vim_nginx.sh',
>             path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
>             require => File['vim_nginx'],
>             onlyif => 'test -e /etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Т.е. тут я создал скрипт, который устанавливает подсветку синтаксиса, копируется на все сервера, относящиеся к заданному классу. Далее отрабатывает проверка на наличие файла /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , что подтверждает установлен ли nginx или нет. Если да, то запускает скрипт.

В принципе это можно использовать с любыми другими зависимостями или даже усовершенствовать логику работы.